# SQOOP IMPORT in avro format fails

Tags: hadoop, import, bigdata, sqoop, avro

SQOOP IMPORT in avro format fails with below error. Please help. Code is given at bottom.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         ... 13 more

script:

```
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --table emp --target-dir /user/edureka/tableemp --username root -p \
--delete-target-dir \
--as-avrodatafile \
--compress \
-m 1 \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved once copied avro mapred jar to sqoop home.